closing and then opening the lid shows verbose stuff in ubuntu
I have a weird thing when closing the lid and then opening, it shows background processes in verbose mode and it wont resume to desktop, it's stuck and i must force-reboot to use the machine.
I've also tried suspending manually, thinking it's just lid problems, i resume it and it gives the same result.
help

system: ubuntu budgie 24.04 lts
dm: lightdm

Within 5 minutes of the event, the terminal command sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes" will show system logs that cover the event.  Each log message starts with a timestamp, the host that issued the log entry, the process name, the PID in [] of the issuer and a colon (:). Everything after the colon is a message from the programmer, intended to help the user understand the program's behavior. Read man logger, for a clearer explanation.

ok, i wrote this command and i've noticed that there were "ACPI BIOS" and "ACPI" errors that go "AE_NOT_FOUND", "AE_ALREADY_EXISTS" and "ACPI BIOS Error (bug)". maybe it's the problem, if it's not the problem, i'll send the full output
